# Why are these two conjugations of 'viaggiare' irregular forms?

Tags: grammar, verbs

Whilst looking up the verb conjugations for *viaggiare* on [WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/conj/ITverbs.aspx?v=viaggiare), I began thinking about this:

[image: conjugation table for viaggiare]

*(blue text means it's an irregular form)*

What I don't quite understand is why these would be considered irregular forms. I can understand that the second-person singular conjugation would be, but why is it the case for the first-person plural? Would it be due to pronunciation or is there something else I'm missing?

**Is there an explanation as to why these are considered irregular?**

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @Texenox!

Comment: I think it's just because it is not "viaggii" and "viaggiiamo".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The forms *viaggi* and *viaggiamo* are irregular because they would be formed (tu) *viaggi**i*** (noi) *viaggi**iamo*** if you were following the normal rules of conjugating present tense verbs.

One forms the stem for present tense conjugations by chopping the -are, -ere or -ire ending and then adding the present endings. So if you create the stem ***viaggi-*** and add the present endings you get a double -i in the second person singular and first person plural conjugations.

Note, however, that sometime verbs do double the ***i***, but only when the -i is stressed in the 1st person present indicative: i.e. sc*i*o, inv*i*o (I send), sp*i*o (I spy). The correct conjugation for these is (tu) *sc**ii*** (invii, spii).

Comment: The *i* in *sciare* is definitely not stressed; *a* is. Perhaps you mean that *i* and *a* belong to different syllables and are pronounced separately. Are you quite sure about *sciiamo*? I never saw it, and Zingarelli dictionary gives *sciamo*.

Comment: You're right about both points. I'll edit the response.

Comment: Still seems about right.

Comment: Yes, @Texenox, I agree with the rest of the answer, and now with all of it (although I myself would not have called these irregular forms, but just forms undergoing standard orthographic adjustments).

Answer (score 4):

No, they aren't irregular forms. The verb belongs to the first conjugation (in *-are*), the same as *amare*

> amo
>   ami
>   ama
>   amiamo
>   amate
>   amano

The only difference is the presence of the *i*, which is just an orthographic device for telling the palatal pronunciation of the preceding (geminated) *g*. So this is a very different situation than *cambiare*, where there is an *i* in the root of the verb. However, the final realization is the same: in both cases the desinence remains *-iamo*; in both cases the *i* in the desinence is absorbed: it's not really heard in *viaggiamo* and it's not doubled in *cambiamo*.

It's a general rule in Italian that pairs of *non-tonic* identical vowels contract to a single one: the plural of *olio* is *oli* and, similarly, any desinence starting with *i* is absorbed:

> cambio
>   cambi (not cambii)
>   cambia
>   cambiamo (not cambiiano)
>   cambiate
>   cambiano

In the case of *viaggiare*, the “purely orthographic” *i* is removed when there is one in the desinence, which avoids any doubt in the pronunciation: so *tu viaggi* and *noi viaggiamo*.

Somebody supports writing plurals of words ending in the diphthong *-io* with a double *i*. Somebody disagrees. But *viaggio* doesn't end with a diphthong, so there should be no doubt that the graphic *i* is dropped when it doesn't serve its purpose any more because a phonetic *i* is present.